# Where are my redis clients being used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, redis, redistogo

I have a Rails 3 app hosted on heroku which at the moment has only one web and one worker dyno. I recently started using Redis as caching database too so I'm performing actions like this (using the redis-rb gem):

```
redis = Redis.new(:host => host, :port => port, :password => password)
redis.set("my_key", some_value)
```

Now I'm getting the following error on my heroku app:

`enter code here`max number of clients reached

I understand that Redis.new will create a new client but I assumed that the connection would be released once the method has completed? Do I need to disconnect the client manually? I've tried redis.destroy & redis.delete but to no avail.

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this as it turns out is that, yes, the redis client has to be closed manually like so

```
redis.quit
```